# What is the fastest way to convert a folder with 10k .txt files into an array (python)

Tags: python

```
corpus = []
for i in tqdm(ways):
  f = open(i,'r')
  print(f.read())
  corpus.append(preprocess_text(f.read()))
  f.close()
```

**ways: array of ways to files in the folder**

*it take to much time (1 hour), can you help me, to make it faster please*

Comment: For starters, remove `print(f.read())` Printing takes a long time. Also, it breaks your code because **this doesn't even work** because you read the entire file object to print and then try to read again to append, but `.read()` the second time will always return an empty string.

Comment: Also, this isn't an array, but a list.

Comment: Firstly, remove the `print`. Next, use a `with` statement instead of manually opening and closing the file. I don't know if that will make a speed difference but it's better practice at least. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: you could also you multiprocessing to map the function. It will use multiple cores instead of a single one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
corpus = [] 
for i in tqdm(ways):    
    with open(i, 'r') as f:       
        corpus.append(preprocess_text(f.read()))
```

This code works faster.